# get javascript file from blobstorage

Tags: jquery, ajax, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to load a javascript file from the azure blobstorage via jQuery.

I cant get it work. I tried the `$.get`, `$.getScript` and normal `$ajax`. 
Can someone tell me whats the right way to do that? I think its a cross domain problem or I am wrong here?

I want to load the file via jQuery and execute it. So when I use a normal `<script>` tag.

```
$.get('..blobUrl.js')
    .success(function(jsResponse) {
        // execute files content
    })



$.ajax({
    url: '...blobUrl.js',
    //dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(response) {
        alert('yeah');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Note the dataType parameter which is set to "script".